# C++ Inheritance: Error: candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance

in the following program, I want to derive a class from a base class. In my code everything seems to be OK. However, I am getting error shown in the below program. Please explain the reason for the error, and how to correct it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Base
{
    int x;
    Base(int x_)
    {
        x=x_;
        cout<<"x="<<x<<endl;
    }
};

struct Derived: public Base
{
    int y;
    Derived(int y_)
    {
        y=y_;
        cout<<"y="<<y<<endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Base B(1);
    Derived D(2);
}
```

This is the error:

```
Output:

 error: no matching function for call to 'Base::Base()
 Note: candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Comment: Your base class's constructor takes an argument. Your derived class must therefore construct the base class appropriately. For more information, see your C++ book.

Answer (score 1):

The default constructor (i.e. `Base::Base()`) will be used to initialize the `Base` subobject of `Derived`, but `Base` doesn't have one.

You could use [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) to specify which constructor of `Base` should be used. e.g.

```
struct Derived: public Base
{
    int y;
    Derived(int y_) : Base(y_)
    //              ~~~~~~~~~~
    {
        y=y_;
        cout<<"y="<<y<<endl;
    }
};
```